# Figures in Minipage to avoid multiple pdf's warning, now labels aren't working

Tags: minipage, labels, warnings, svg

I'm trying to include svg graphics in combination with the respective .pdf_txt within my bachelor thesis. So far that works but it triggers the Warning : `'multiple pdf's in a page group'`. That Warning is said to be harmless but I find it really annoying because I have a lot of graphics to include. In one of the forums I found the option to shut off those warnings with `\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1`. That just gives me an undefined control sequence and saving the svg as an older pdf version didn't work either.

So I tried to put each graphic into a `minipage`. So far that seems to work and the warnings for the page groups went away. Now I get the warning that my labels are undefined. Does anyone have an idea why that suddenly appeared? The references were working fine before.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[th]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\includesvg{Anforderung}
\caption{Anforderungen}
\label{anfo}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
Text \ref{anfo}
\end{document}
```

Sample svg file

```
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
>
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>

    <rect x="400" y="100" width="400" height="200"
        fill="yellow" stroke="navy" stroke-width="10"  />

</svg>
```

Comment: That's what I though, too but without the minipage I get those warnings about multiple pdf's within a page group so I thought that putting each graphic within its own 'page' would avoid that and it apparently does. But the labels aren't working anymore even though I didn't change anything there. The labels are still directly below the caption. But for the \ref{} they seem to be undefined.

Comment: Are you sure that the `\label` is still directly after the `\caption`? If the `\end{minipage}` separates both you can get problems when using the caption package.

Comment: yes I'm sure. I tried switching places with no effect and the \label are back right below the \caption

Comment: Please correct the errors in your example (`onesided` -> `oneside`; `graphics` -> `graphicx`, make the labels etc. non-empty) till it gives a compilable file that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I just looked at the final document and those entries disappeard from the table of figures, too. 
@ David Carlisle could you tell me what kind of example you want? Or what kind of further information you need? As far as I can tell the example given above describes my Problem since I didn't change anything else from before those warnings came up.

Comment: I have the \figure environment outside the \minipage (as shown above) and I don't get errors just those warnings and the captions don't show up within the list of figures anymore or anywhere else within the document

Comment: Your new example (if I ignore the missing files errors) does not generate an undefined reference on the second run of latex (always needs at least two runs to resolve cross reverences) so it doesn't seem to be an example of an undefined reference problem, and as the svg image is not available it doesn't generate the multiple pdf's in a page group error so dosn't help debug that

Comment: I always make several runs before I take any warnings serious. Those Warnings don't disappear. It happend before that some warnings or errors were shown when something completly different was wrong. Could this be one of those times too? As for my svg picture, if I try to implement just the .pdf or a .png LaTeX won't compile the text within the svg. The graphic contains a couple of colored squares containing text, no transparency and nothing to complicated.

Comment: I just tried to upload one of the pictures in that generates the warning 'multiple pdf's with page group' but .svg is not treated as a picture here. It's really just a stack of colored squares

Comment: I will add a small svg file to your question If I save that as `Anforderung.svg` and run `pdflatex --shell-escape file` twice on your file I get no warnings and the svg is included. If you do not get that, try to replace the svg with an image that does cause problems.